# Sorting in XSLT within nested For Each

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a list of Faculties, within each of which is a list of departments. I want to display the entire list of departments, sorted by Department name, but indicating the faculty.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Faculties>

  <Faculty Name="Science">
    <Department name="dept2">
      <head>Mr X</head>
      <building>A Block</building>
      etc...
   </Department>
   <Department name="dept3">
      <head>Mr X</head>
      <building>B Block</building>
      etc...
   </Department>
  </Faculty>

  <Faculty Name="Education">
    <Department name="dept1">
      <head>Mr Y</head>
      <building>C Block</building>
      etc...
    </Department>
  </Faculty>

</Faculties>
```

The XSLT looks something like this: (I've simplified the XSLT for explanation purposes.)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Faculties">
  <xsl:sort select="DepartmentName">
  <xsl:for-each select="Departments">
    <xsl:element name="div">
      <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="facultName"></xsl:attribute>
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="deptName"> - <xsl:value-of select="facultName"></h3>
      //More stuff here
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
Dept1 (Education)
Head: Mr Y
Building: C Block

Dept2 (Science)
Head: Mr X
Building: A Block

Dept3 (Science)
Head: Mr X
Building: B Block
```

Where it's sorted by Department Name.

I also want to be able to hide all the departments from a particular faculty using Javascript, i.e. hide all divs which have a particular faculty in the id.

I'm not even sure if what I'm attempting is possible (or logical). My only other option seems to be generating a completely new list of departments, with faculty as one of the elements. Then I'll only need one for-each. Unfortunately, I can't really control how the XML is generated, so I'm hoping to be able to do it this way.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the source XML document, which you forgot to show. Also, provide the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to list all departments in name order, regardless of the faculty, you can simply iterate over the departments directly

```
<xsl:for-each select="Faculty/Department">
   <xsl:sort select="@deptName" />

</xsl:for-each>
```

Then, to get the faculty name for the department, you can access the parent element quite easily

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@facultyName" />
```

So, assuming you have the following XML

```
<Faculties>
   <Faculty id="1" facultyName="Beer Drinking">
      <Department id="1" deptName="Real Ale" />
      <Department id="2" deptName="Lager" />
   </Faculty>
   <Faculty id="2" facultyName="Food">
      <Department id="3" deptName="Fish and Chips" />
      <Department id="4" deptName="Pies" />
   </Faculty>
</Faculties>
```

When you apply the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Faculties">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Faculty/Department">
         <xsl:sort select="@deptName" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Department">
      <div id="{../@facultyName}">
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="concat(@deptName, ' - ', ../@facultyName)" /></h3>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is output

```
<div id="Food">
   <h3>Fish and Chips - Food</h3>
</div>
<div id="Beer Drinking">
   <h3>Lager - Beer Drinking</h3>
</div>
<div id="Food">
   <h3>Pies - Food</h3>
</div>
<div id="Beer Drinking">
   <h3>Real Ale - Beer Drinking</h3>
</div>
```

Do note, it is usually preferably to use **xsl:apply-templates** over **xsl:for-each**, and so this is what I have used in the XSLT.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! Thank you so much! And thanks for the really quick reply. Your solution is so elegant.

Comment: Just applied your solution to my project and it worked like a charm. Thanks again!